# switching two power sources

Tags: power-supply, dc, circuits

I have used the circuit below to switch between two power sources. The purpose was to have a backup power source once the other is switched off by a controller in the system.
While testing the operation of the circuit I have noticed that when one of the sources is ON (15V at VS1 for example) and the other is OFF (VS2) there is a voltage of(14V) at the anode of the OFF source schottky(VS2 in this case).
Could the reason for this be the diode parasitic capacitor charging through the reverse leakage current?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not the capacitance. You are just measuring the effect of leakage current via the schottky diode as voltage when the multimeter completes the circuit with its impedance. If you use the multimeter to measure voltage over the non-conducting schottky diode, you will get very near zero volts, which means that both ends of the diode are at same voltage of Vout when measuring it.